# Regex - get "1,546 messages" string inside list

Tags: regex

The whole message is that:

```
1st. @Aarian ™: `3,175 messages`
2nd. @PreEdition: `3,136 messages`
3rd. @Tyzes : `2,767 messages`
4th. @Brot: `2,500 messages`
5th. @Gamerbow3115: `1,869 messages`
```

But I only want to get the part inside the `` from the first 3 dudes. But just to know, the message number can always be different, like the @Mentions.

The only thing that is everytime the same is that the messages part is always inside a `` and after a @Mention:

Comment: `[\d,]+\smessages`

Comment: Copy+paste `(?:^.*?([\d,]+ messages(?=\`$)).*$\s)` 3 times and retrieve capture group #1

Comment: And what if its `65 hours, 25 minutes` and not `1,236 messages` ?

Comment: Then you need to ask a better question, you only mention messages in the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about first extracting the 3 first lines (because the rest isn't important) and then running this regular expression:

```regex
/^(?:1st|2nd|3rd)\.\s*@(.*?):\s*`([^`]+)`\s*$/gm
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/9Gnpnp/1

Explanation:

- Use the `m` modifier so that the regex is tested per line and not on all the content.
- Use the `g` modifier to execute it for all matches (and not stop on the first match). Only do that if you extracted the 3 first lines before.
- `^` means starting with.
- `(?:1st|2nd|3rd)` means a non-capturing group `(?:)` containing either "1st", "2nd" or "3rd"
- `\.\s*@` just looks for a dot followed or not by spaces and the "@" symbol.
- `(.*?)` is to capture the user name (group n°1).
- It's then followed by `:\s*` which is ":" followed or not by spaces.
- Then we want to find the message which is surrounded by backticks: `` `([^`]+)` ``. To capture the message inside we want to match all chars which are not a backtick.
- We then finish by some optional spaces: `\s*$`

Comment: How can this work if "the message number can always be different"?

Comment: @horcrux : well, I capture any message surrounded by backticks. But as he only wants to capture the 3 first guys from the list, I assumed that only `1st`, `2nd` and `3rd` have to be matched at the beginning of the line. But it’s also because he added a new case to his question . At the beginning it was only for “n messages” and then it was also for ranking persons by the time spent.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

If you want to do it with only one match, you can use the following:

```
(?s)^.*?\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)\. @[^`]*`([^`]*)`\s*\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)\. @[^`]*`([^`]*)`\s*\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)\. @[^`]*`([^`]*)`
```

and then refer to the first 3 capturing groups (see [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/k5DvgR/1)).

#### Solution 2

Otherwise, simply use this:

```
(?m)^\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)\. @[^`]*`([^`]*)`\s*
```

referring to the first capturing group only for the first 3 matches (see [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/9gq28t/1)).